# Pycharm Edutools Course Cannot open the page

Tags: python, pycharm

I have problem with a Course in Pycharm. All was good but now I have the problem because it doesn't show description

Can you help me why ?

I have Pycharm 3.9

Here is image:

[image]

If I start course description show me and if I refresh show cannot open

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the Task Description panel to Swing in **Help | Find Action | Switch Task Description Panel**. See the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/EDU-3968